# Bqplot numbers exceed limit

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, bqplot

I've been using bqplot in jupyter notebook recently.

The numbers that I want to plot is stored in a numpy array. However, when they are plotted, some numbers become negative. I suspect the problem is int conversion and two's complement. I checked that number type if **numpy.uint64**,and many numbers in the array are larger than 2^^32. So this is probably where the problem is.

Is there a way to fix this in the bqplot setting?